# Intuitive way to understand the triangle spectrum?

Tags: fourier-transform

Image on the top is in the time domain, image on the bottom is in the frequency domain. [image]

Why do we see -2T and 2T on image of the time domain and why do we see -1/2T and 1/2T of the image in the frequency domain?

Comment: What does this have to do with computer science specifically? This might be better suited to http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I would have suggested http://dsp.stackexchange.com/, but it got a good answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there is a sound with frequency 440Hz. How large is each period of this periodic signal? It must be (1/440)s. The same applies in your case.